# Use non-system ruby to execute ruby scripts within macOS App

Tags: ruby, swift, xcode, macos, nstask

I'm building an macOS app which needs to execute a framework written in ruby. Currently with macOS High Sierra 10.13.x the system ruby version is only 2.3.3. I'm using brew / rvm (it depends) to install up to date versions.

When trying to run `/usr/local/bin/ruby` or `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby` with `Process` Xcode throws the error that `Operation is not permitted`.

This works fine when using `/usr/bin/ruby` as `launchPath`.

Is there a way to execute ruby from `/usr/local/bin/ruby` or `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby` or any other custom paths?

With the current version of macOS it is also not possible to update the symbolic link of `/usr/bin/ruby` to a different binary.

Here is my implementation so far:

```
let myScript = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myScript", ofType: "command")

let task = Process()    
task.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
task.arguments = myScript, basePath
taks.launch()
```

And here is `myScript` content:

```
#!/bin/sh -l

BASE_PATH="$1"
cd "${BASE_PATH}"

/usr/local/bin/ruby my_ruby_script.rb
```

When I launch the task I got this message:

```
 /usr/local/bin/ruby: Operation not permitted
```

or

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby: Operation not permitted
```

Hope you have a solution.

Comment: Is "/usr/local/bin/ruby" an executable file for which you have read and execute permission? Can you execute `/usr/local/bin/ruby my_ruby_script.rb` in a Terminal?

Comment: Yes that works.

Comment: Is sandboxing activated?

Comment: Awesome! Yes that was the problem. Thank you. During development I'm deactivating it and later on I will search for a proper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to [Martin R's help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48463688/use-non-system-ruby-to-execute-ruby-scripts-withing-macos-app#comment83921133_48463688) I was able to solve the issue.
For now I deactivated macOS sandboxing in the projects capabilities.

Now I can use any ruby I want.

Thank you